# Issues while publishing a Windows phone app in the Windows Store

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, publishing

I am trying to upload a windows phone app on store. The previous version which was uploaded is 4.0.0.0 and the new package which I am trying to upload is v4.1.0.0.

As per my understanding v4.1.0.0 is higher than v4.0.0.0. I dont understand why I am getting the below error

Error message from Windows :
You’ve uploaded another package with the same properties as this one. When this submission is published, the other package will replace this one.
This package (4.1.0.0) will be removed after you save this page because you have a higher-versioned package that supports the same customers.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the package v.4.0.0.0 manually and save only v.4.1.0.0